# Changing Background Image in Multiple Terminals

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, bashrc, desktop-background

I was wondering if anyone would know how to change the background image in the terminal in a unique way.

I know how to change it so that every instance of the terminal has the same background, but I occasionally end up using 2 or 3 terminals to work in different paths.

I was wondering if there is a way to set some like

- Terminal 1: Image 1
- Terminal 2: Image 2
- Terminal 3: Image 3
- ...
- Terminal N: Image N

**EDIT**
I was hoping to do this by developing a technique that would look through an assortment of profiles, previously defined by me, and each time I opened a terminal it would cycle through the next profile until it reaches the end and then it restarts. I am not sure what the best approach would be to this. Maybe an addition to `~/.bash_aliases` that defines the profiles and sets the terminal to change depending on the amount of times a terminal has been opened in that session.

Comment: Which terminal (Xfce, Gnome, KDE (Konsole), Terminator...). You can with some terminal use a 'profiles', the amount you have is probably only limited to the amount you create (you may be able to automate this), and you will probably have to do something to detect how many terminals are running (N) and make a new terminal with N+1 background

Comment: @Wilf I just have the standard Gnome I believe. Whatever comes with the installation of Ubuntu 14.04. I haven't messed around with other terminals. Which are the ones that allow the use of profiles?

Comment: A few of them... looking at the `--help` options both Gnome Terminal and Konsole allow the selection of profiles via command line, which may be useful

Comment: @Wilf Alright so I understand that, I guess I am looking for a really interesting result for the answer of this question. The ideal result would be that every time I opened a terminal it cycled through a new profile, or thus a new background picture, and as soon as it came to the last image it would restart. Kinda like a slideshow except for the terminal. Think this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

**What will you need ?** xdotool (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`) and couple different profiles. I have 8 different profiles in my gnome-terminal , all with different colors or background settings. Make sure you have the menu bar (File, Edit, etc.) enabled. Otherwise - won't work

**The command**

`xdotool key alt+f b $( expr $RANDOM % 8 )`

*Explanation*: we get a random number $RANDOM as generated by the shell, get it's modulus (remainder) out of division by maximum number of profiles you have, and let `xdotool` execute sequence of keyboard shortcuts that correspond to dropping down `File` (alt+f) menu, selecting `open new tab` (b), and selecting profile with corresponding number

You can turn this command into an alias (`alias newtab='xdotool key alt+f b $( expr $RANDOM % 8 )'`) or script

I've taken that very same alias and placed it into my `.mkshrc` file (because I use mksh, not bash, so for you it's .bashrc). Here it is in action

[image]

**Update | April 22, 2015**

Here's a script to open a terminal window with your desired profile (and for each profile you can specify your own colors and background picture). Bind it to a keyboard shortcut through System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom. 
For the command add full path to script
[image]
[image]

**The script**

```
#!/bin/bash

PROFILE=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter Profile Name")
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile="$PROFILE" &
```

Comment: Let me know if you cannot see the animation. I'll post a link to it

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I have been relatively busy and I honestly forgot about this, I am attempting your solution now, will provide results soon.

Comment: Okay, this isn't quite what I am looking for.  And I will explain why, what I was hoping to get was something that opened new windows as opposed to new tabs, or change the existing tab. I was also looking for something that would decide by me opening the terminal window,  something where 'newtab' was called as soon as a new window was opened.  Does that make sense?

Comment: well, changing already open window can be done only through profile preferences(right click); and if you set up N different profiles, then opening new window with that profile will give you that, basically press Alt+F2, and run `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=nameoftheprofile`.  I'll add another script to my answer, which you can bind to keyboard, and instead of typing full command, just type name of the profile there

Comment: I'll to work on this later this weekend, but so far I have no ideas. There should be ways to achieve what you want, it's just takes time to figure out