# 18.04 Multiple terminals each with its own background color

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 18.04, I am working with multiple terminal windows and I'd like to change the color of each one so I can keep them straight. The preferences for the terminal application changes the background color of all terminal windows.

Comment: Would it work for you to just change the color of each terminal's tab when you have multiple windows? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045901/is-it-possible-to-apply-different-colors-to-terminal-tabs-in-gnome-based-on-the explains how.

Comment: Or, does this answer your question? [Changing Background Image in Multiple Terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593616/changing-background-image-in-multiple-terminals)

Comment: Not duplicate of those. The first one you linked is about changing the *tab* color, and the answer doesn't answer that at all. The second one is about background *image*, something gnome-terminal no longer supports.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a terminal.
2. Go to

   *Edit → Preferences → Profiles*
3. Click on the "plus" button
4. Add the name of the new profile and change its settings
5. Go to

   *Terminal → Change profile*

   you will have a list of your created profiles. Change at will in each new opened terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This command changes the background color in the given terminal only:

```
xtermcontrol --bg="#abcdef"
```

or alternatively

```
printf "\e]11;#abcdef\e\\"
```

Place this in your shell startup file, and combine with randomness (or derive the color from `tty`'s output) as you please.